# Facebook PHP SDK exception error

Tags: php, facebook

I am getting an interesting SDK exception message from FB's PHP SDK. I set up my code exactly as the FB docs say to do..?

DEBUG ERROR MESSAGE:

```
[12-Jun-2014 21:08:12 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookSDKException' with message 'Session not active, could not store state.' in C:\WebRoot\Website\root\inc\Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php:188
Stack trace:
#0 C:\WebRoot\Website\root\inc\Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php(94):Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper->storeState('**********...')
#1 C:\WebRoot\Website\root\login\index.php(87): Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper->getLoginUrl()
#2 {main}
   thrown in C:\WebRoot\Website\root\inc\Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php on line 188
```

Facebook.php:

```
<?php
require_once("../inc/config.php");
require_once(ROOT_PATH . 'inc/Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once(ROOT_PATH . 'inc/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once(ROOT_PATH . 'inc/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once(ROOT_PATH . 'inc/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once(ROOT_PATH . 'inc/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once(ROOT_PATH . 'inc/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once(ROOT_PATH . 'inc/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once(ROOT_PATH . 'inc/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once(ROOT_PATH . 'inc/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once(ROOT_PATH . 'inc/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once(ROOT_PATH . 'inc/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;

// init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication("**********","*******************");
```

Main Login Page:

```
<?php
require_once("../inc/config.php");
require_once(ROOT_PATH . 'inc/Facebook/Facebook.php' );
require_once(ROOT_PATH . "inc/LoginHelper.php");

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;

session_start();

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( '***********' );
```

Link on main login page:

```
<a href="<?php echo $helper->getLoginUrl();?>"><img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>img/facebook-login-button.png" class="fb-login"></a>
```

Redirect url page:

```
<?php
require_once("../inc/config.php");
require_once(ROOT_PATH . 'inc/Facebook/Facebook.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;

session_start();

//get user login token from FB
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('*******');
try {
   $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
     echo $ex;
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch(Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex;
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}
if ($session) {
    $FacebookAccessToken = $session->getToken();
   // Logged in
}
```

Comment: Put `session_start();` on top of each file...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put `session_start();` on the TOP of your file

Answer (score 13):

To expand Chancho's answer, the SDK will check to see if a session is active before it tries to store any data to it. There are 3 ways around this.

## Start a native PHP session

If you're just using PHP's native sessions, Chancho's answer will suffice. You have to make sure that `session_start();` is at the very top of your script before any output is sent.

## Overwrite the session handling

If you're using a web framework like Codeigniter, Yii, CakePHP, Laravel, etc, they usually have their own ways of storing a session. To overwrite the default session store, you'll need to write your own class that extends the `\Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper` class. Then you'll need to overwrite the `storeState()` and `loadState()` methods. These are the only two methods in the whole SDK that interface with the `$_SESSION` variable.

You can see a [laravel implementation example](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/issues/39#issuecomment-42363729) in the GitHub issues for the SDK. Here's the laravel implementation:

```
class MyFacebookRedirectLoginHelper extends \Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper
{
  protected function storeState($state)
  {
    Session::put('state', $state);
  }

  protected function loadState()
  {
    return $this->state = Session::get('state');
  }
}
```

## Disable the session check completely

If you're trying to use the SDK in a stateless environment like the command line, there's no point in starting a session or overwriting how the session data is stored. You can simply disable the check with `FacebookRedirectLoginHelper::disableSessionStatusCheck()`.

To disable the session check just run this.

```
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('*******');

$helper->disableSessionStatusCheck();

$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

// . . .
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Good solution! I'm using Laravel 4

Comment: It seems this does not work anymore with the newer SDK. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

For using CakePHP v3.1.6 + Facebook SDK v4.1.

In the newer SDK, \Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper class has been changed to use \Facebook\FacebookSessionPersistentDataHandler class to handle session "state". Putting $this->request->session()->start() in AppController initialize will fix the problem using Facebook SDK with AuthComponent.

```
public function initialize() {
    parent::initialize();
    $this->request->session()->start();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');

    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => ['username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password']
            ]
        ],
        'loginAction' => ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']
    ]);
}
```